# Can we have $\log(\frac{1}{x})<x$ as $x$ small enough?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Can we have
$$\log(\frac{1}{x})<x$$
as $x$ small enough?

I knew that $$\log(x)<x$$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Answer is NO. As $x \to 0+$ right side tends to $0$ an left side tends to $\infty$.

Comment: You have $\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)<x$ for $x$ big enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, $$\ln (\frac 1x)<x$$
So, $$-\ln (x)<x$$
So, $$\ln (x)>-x$$
Now draw the graph of these two functions, you'll see that if $x$ is small enough, $y=-x$ is larger, and not smaller, than $\ln (x)$. Hence, the answer to your question, is no.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log(1/x) = -\log(x) = x$$
$$x e^{x} = 1 \implies x = W(1) \approx 0.567 \text{ , where W is the Lambert W function}$$
Since $-\log(x)$ is strictly decreasing and $x$ is strictly increasing, than
$$\log(1/x) \ge x ~,~ \forall x \in (0, W(1)]$$
$$\log(1/x) \le x ~,~ \forall x \in [W(1), \infty)$$